# is docker-py/dockerpy secure to use?

Tags: docker, dockerpy

I've been reading about security issues with building docker images within a docker container by mounting the docker socket.

In my case, I am accessing docker via an API , docker-py.

Now I am wondering, are there security issues with building images using docker-py on a plain ubuntu host (not in a docker container) since it also communicates on the docker socket?

I'm also confused as to why there would be security differences between running docker from the command line vs this sdk, since they both go through the socket?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference, if you have access to the socket, you can send a request to run a container with access matching that of the dockerd engine. That engine is typically running directly on the host as root, so you can use the API to get root access directly on the host.

Methods to lock this down include running the dockerd daemon inside of a container, however that container is typically privileged which itself is not secure, so you can gain root in the other container and use the privileged access to gain root on the host.

The best options I've seen include running the engine rootless, and an escape from the container would only get you access to the user the daemon is running as. However, realize rootless has it's drawbacks, including needing to pre-configure the host to support this, and networking and filesystem configuration being done at the user level which has functionality and performance implications. And the second good option is to run the build without a container runtime at all, however this has it's own drawbacks, like not having a 1-for-1 replacement of the Dockerfile `RUN` syntax, so your image is built mainly from the equivalent of `COPY` steps plus commands run on the host outside of any container.